# Partition list into $n$ sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Is there an inbuilt function/option or an elegant composition of functions for partitioning a list into exactly $n$ sublists? I played around with `Partition` and its options but could not find anything suitable by itself. The general requirement is that the `Length` of the resulting splitted list is $n$. A few interesting corner cases:

- Splitting a list into $n=1$ parts should result in the list wrapped with `List`, e.g. splitting `{1,2,3}` into $n=1$ parts yields `{{1,2,3}}` because `Length[{{1,2,3}}]` is `1`
- Splitting lists with fewer than $n$ elements by padding with empty lists e.g. `{1,2}`into $n=3$ parts should yield `{{1}, {2}, {}}`
- Splitting lists of uneven length into an even number of parts or vice versa e.g. `{1,2,3}` into $n=2$ parts should either yield `{{1,2},{3}}` or `{{1}, {2,3}}`. It doesn't matter to me which, but behavior should be consistent.

Right now I use

```
ClearAll@splitList;
splitList[1][list_] := {list};
splitList[parts_Integer][list_] := 
  With[{n = Ceiling[Length[list]/parts]}, 
     Partition[list, UpTo[n]] // 
     Replace[
      {prev : Repeated[{___}, parts - 1]} :> 
      {prev, Apply[Sequence]@Table[{}, {parts - Length@{prev}}] } 
     ]
  ]
```

I feel that the concept of splitting a list into exactly $n$ sublists is something that is easy to express but involves difficult corner cases and thus could be something that is already implemented in Mathematica, much like with regular `Partition` and `UpTo`.

Comment: In your program, `splitList[4][Range[9]]` returns `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {}}` is it intended? How about `{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{},{},{}}`?

Comment: @happy fish thanks for this observation; this is yet another corner case that is ill defined and does depend on what one wishes to accomplish. My application uses only needs the special case $n=2$ and I want chunks of equal size where possible but any solution is interesting in the scope of this broader question. In a build-in function I would expect the partitioning scheme as an option.

Comment: @happyfish, yes your code is a possible solution

Comment: OK, I undeleted my answer. But I think it is not very contributive after all...

Answer (score 5):

This seems to return same results as your code:

```
ms = PadRight[Partition[#, UpTo[Ceiling[Length[#]/#2]]], #2, {{}}]&;
```

Check:

```
r1 = splitList[#][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] & /@ Range[1, 10];
r2 = ms[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, #] & /@ Range[1, 10];
r1 == r2
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the job:

```
spl[lst_, n_] := TakeList[lst, Subdivide[1, Length@lst + 1, n] // Round // Differences];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) seems quite clean to my eye, even with replacement for null padding.  It also works in v9.0 and after, whereas [`UpTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html) was introduced in v10.3.

```
Module[{x},
  splitIn[p_Integer?Positive][a_?ListQ] :=
    ArrayReshape[a, {p, ⌈Length@a/p⌉}, x] /. x -> Sequence[]
]
```

Comment: Also `DeleteCases[
 ArrayReshape[a, {p, \[LeftCeiling]Length@a/p\[RightCeiling]}, x], x,
  2]` ... +1

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version.

```
p[list_, n_] := 
 Module[{res = Partition[list, UpTo[Ceiling[Length[list]/n]]]}, 
  Join[res, Table[{}, n - Length[res]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I have understood this. Perhaps this will motivate clarification or the correct or better answer:

```
f[a_, n_] := 
 Module[{a2}, (If[n > Length[a], a2 = PadRight[a, n], a2 = a]; 
   Internal`PartitionRagged[a2, #] & /@ 
     Permutations[IntegerPartitions[Length[a2], {n}][[1]]] /. {0 -> 
      Sequence[]})]
```

e.g. `Grid[{Range@#, f[Range@#, 4]} & /@ Range[3, 10]]`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `{}` should only be used when `n` is greater than `Length[list]`:

```
split[L_, n_] := PadRight[MapThread[L[[Span[##]]] &, {Most[# + 1], Rest[#]} &[
                      Round[Range[0, #, Max[#/n, 1]] &[Length[L]]]]], {n}, {{}}]

list = Range[17];
p[list, 1]
p[list, 12]
p[list, 25]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}}
>
> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11}, {12, 
>     13}, {14}, {15, 16}, {17}}
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, \
>   {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}