# Shortest way to take first half of list and/or split list into n parts

Tags: functions, function-construction

What is the shortest way to take the first half of a list? Or to split a list into `n` equal parts? If the length is not 0 mod n, I would prefer to leave out the left over elements (that is more consistent with for example the behaviour of Partition, e.g. `Partition[Array[a, 7], 3]`). It feels like I am missing a basic elementary way to do this. Is there anything simpler than something like

```
#[[;; Floor[Length[#]/2]]] &
```

It feels like there should be something like `Partition` or `[[;; ;;2]]` that splits consecutively but I couldn't find it.

Comment: [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) - this is easy to find in the documentation - I don't know how you missed it - if you want the irregular elements using `UpTo` in `Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, UpTo[3]]` gives {{a,b,c},{d,e}}

Comment: @flinty, that does not do what I want right? The 3 that you specify is the number upto which it includes not the number of partitions right? So the whole point would be that you have to figure out the correct partitions by taking Length[#]/n etc. So I don't see how that would help. You would basically resort to my example but more complicated. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Kvothe, yes in that case you would have to calculate the length. Also this is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141173/partition-list-into-n-sublists . I just fixed a bug on an answer on that page, which is the best one in my opinion: `spl[lst_, n_] := TakeList[lst, Subdivide[1, Length@lst + 1, n] // Round // Differences];`

Comment: Hmm, yes I had not found that one. It could be marked as a duplicate, although some of the specifications required there for cases where Length[list] =!= 0 mod n are quite bad and against Mathematica conventions. I would prefer behavior consistent with for example `Partition[Array[a, 7], 3]`, i.e. leaving out superflous elements. I will edit my question to make a clear difference (and leave it up to the Stackexchange gods to see whether it is different enough).

Comment: I think `Partition` is already good enough. You cannot expect that everything is built-in. (But maybe there're undocumented functions to do this)

Comment: Take a look at [NearEqualPartition](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NearEqualPartition).

Comment: From the link supplied by @RohitNamjoshi, `RatioPartition` seems to be another possibility:  `ResourceFunction["RatioPartition"][Range[21], {50,50}]`

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I have to admit this is kind of cheating, but, since *Mathematica* hasn't had an ad hoc function for the frequently-used list equi-division... we can write a shorthand by ourselves?

```
ClearAll[Backslash];
Backslash[
  ls_?ListQ /; (D`len = Length[ls]; True),
  n_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= n <= D`len && (D`n = n; True),
  Optional[nth_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= nth <= D`n, All]
 ] := If[D`m = D`len~Quotient~n; nth === All,
    Partition[ls, D`m][[;; n]],
    ls[[(nth - 1) D`m + 1 ;; nth*D`m]]
]
```

Then you can *ignore it* and type like `Esc` `\` `Esc` `4` to split a list into 4 equi-length sublists (leaving out the leftover elements):

```
Range[10]\4 (* \ = \[Backslash] *)
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
> ```

Take the first half of a list:

```
Range[10]\2\1
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

They **don't need to be of strictly equal size**? Not a problem. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3652905/654489), we can make modifications:

```
ClearAll[Backslash];
Backslash[
  ls_?ListQ /; (D`len = Length[ls]; True),
  n_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= n <= D`len && (D`n = n; True),
  Optional[nth_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= nth <= D`n, All]
 ] := If[nth === All,
  ls~TakeList~Table[Quotient[D`len + k, n], {k, 0, n - 1}],
  ls[[(D`s = Sum[Quotient[D`len + k, n], {k, 0, nth - 2}]) + 1
     ;; D`s + Quotient[D`len + nth - 1, n]]]
]
```

Example:

```
Range[10]\4
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}}
> ```

```
Range[10]\4\3
```

> ```
> {5, 6, 7}
> ```

The query part is short, although... Alright, just take this as humor.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
list = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
n = Floor[Length[list]/2];
list2 = Drop[list, n]
list3 = Drop[list, -n]
```

Comment: I understand that you can do something simple like this. Indeed I included one such example in the question. And indeed I might resort to a hand constructed function doing something like this. (Although in that case I would like a more general form splitIntoParts[n_] that splits into n parts.) But really this action seems so elementary that I was hoping that either there was a built in function I missed or that someone could do it in a very small easily readable one liner.